# TemplateUrl not working with JIT compile Angular4 with webpack

Tags: angular, webpack

If I use AOT evertying works ok but if I change to JIT....

Get error:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'home.html'
    at Error (native)
```

Here is how my component looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable'

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: './home.html'
})

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    ngOnInit() {
        let src = Observable.of(10);

        var subscription = src.subscribe(
            (x: any) => console.log('onNext: %s', x),
            (e: any) => console.log('onError: %s', e),
            () => console.log('onCompleted'));

    }
}
```

And main module:

```
// Angular
import '@angular/platform-browser';
import '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import '@angular/core';
import '@angular/common';

// RxJS
import 'rxjs';

// Other vendors for example jQuery, Lodash or Bootstrap
// You can import js, ts, css, sass, ...


import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';

import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';


// import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
// import { AppClientModuleNgFactory } from '../built/src/app/app.client.module.ngfactory';
import { AppClientModule } from './app/app.client.module';

// platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppClientModuleNgFactory);
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppClientModule);
```

Anyone know what can be a problem? I tried to `moduleId: module.id.toString(),` to component also I tried to add full path but not working same error.

Comment: do you use systemjs?

Comment: Using webpack and angular universal as well